# Upgrading Windows 7's PowerShell v3, to Windows 8's PowerShell v3

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, powershell-3.0

I have becoming increasingly aware that Windows 7's PowerShell v3 lacks cmdlets / functions and modules found in Windows 8's version of PowerShell 3.  My question: Is there anyway of 'upgrading' PowerShell v3 in Windows 7 to that of Windows 8?  Have I missed a link on Microsoft's site to download the extra modules?

A second best outcome would be a list of Windows 7's 'missing' version 3.0 modules and their cmdlets / functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot install certain cmdlets (even by copying the modules folder from Windows 8) because Windows 7 does not have the underlying WMI classes.

Richard Siddaway provides a complete answer, and a list of the differences, in his [PowerShell blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/richardsiddaway/archive/2012/12/14/powershell-v3-installed-modules.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

no, this is "by design". The Windows 7 version doesn't includes all cmdlets.

Run this to see which cmdlets are added in Powershel 3.0:

```
Get-Command -CommandType cmdlet | Foreach-Object { get-help $_ } |

select name, description |

where description -match "This cmdlet is introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0" |

Format-Table -AutoSize –Wrap
```

[image]

**Source:**

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/08/weekend-scripter-exploring-new-and-improved-powershell-3-0-cmdlets.aspx

Comment: Neat idea, promising script for research.  Windows 7.count =38.  Windows 8.count =41 (conclusion there is a difference between the two versions of PowerShell 3.0.  Problem 1) Some of Window 8's cmdlets lie, they are new, but their description does not tell you, for example Get-NetAdapter in Windows 8.  Problem 2) there are cmdlet-like functions.  Here the score is Windows 7.count = 147, Window 8.count = 593.  Just to restate my quest, to get a download package for those missing modules / cmdlets / functions.

Comment: Ask in the Microsoft Blog (as comment) about a list of missing cmdlets.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to download and install Windows Management Framework 3.0 from the Microsoft Download Center. (KB 2406143).

Comment: This does not address the fact that, due to OS limitations, Windows 8 has PowerShell cmdlets which are not available to Windows 7.